# EB5 Green Card : Can it conflict with EB2 Green Card Application

Tags: h1-visa, greencard

I have a question about the EB5 GC. Lets say I am working on H1-B and my employer has filed for my GC under EB2 category.

Now, if i apply for the EB5 GC, will this new application conflict with the existing one filed by my employer?

Is it possible to have 2 separate GC applications albeit under different categories?

Comment: https://www.eb5investors.com/qa/how-to-apply-for-eb2-and-eb5